# What is causing Error TypeError: text is not iterable? - Web scraper Puppeteer NodeJs

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer, csv-parser

I am learning nodejs/puppeteer and having issues getting Puppeteer to fill UPC numbers from a CSV file onto the search bar of a book website. I managed to get a the web scraper to scrape the website if I use a single UPC number.

But I am getting the below error when I used async function to CSV-Parse the UPC values from the CSV to the web scraper

```
(node:5876) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: text is not iterable
```

This is the sample CSV

```
DATE,QUANTITY,NAME,CODECONTENT,CODETYPE
2021-10-13 20:16:44 +1100,1,"Book 1","9781250035288",9
2021-10-13 20:16:40 +1100,1,"Book 2","9781847245601",9
2021-10-13 20:16:35 +1100,1,"Book 3","9780007149247",9
2021-10-13 20:16:30 +1100,1,"Book 4","9780749958084",9
2021-10-13 20:16:26 +1100,1,"Book 5","9781405920384",9
```

Is there something wrong with the way I am parsing the CSV?

```
function readCsvAsync(filename, delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8') {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const rows = [];
        try {
            fs.createReadStream(filename, {encoding: encoding})
                .pipe(parse({delimiter: delimiter}))
                .on('data', (row) => rows.push(+row.CODECONTENT))
                .on('end', () => resolve(rows))
                .on('error', reject);
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}

async function upcData() {
    try {
        const rows = await readCsvAsync('Book_Bulk.csv', ':');
        // console.log(csvData);
        // call puppeteer or whatever
        return rows;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

---

**Full code below:**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const parse = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');


async function getpageData(page,upc){
    await page.goto('https://www.bookdepository.com/');
    await page.type('#book-search-form > div.el-wrap.header-search-el-wrap > input.text-input',upc);
    await page.click('#book-search-form > div.el-wrap.header-search-el-wrap > button');
    
    //Title
    await page.waitForSelector('.item-info h1');
    const title = await page.$eval('.item-info h1', h1 => h1.textContent);

    //Author
    await page.waitForSelector('div.author-info.hidden-md > span > a > span');
    const author = await page.$eval('div.author-info.hidden-md > span > a > span', span => span.innerText);

    //Genre
    await page.waitForSelector('.active a');
    const genre = await page.$eval('.active a', a => a.innerText);

    //Format
    await page.waitForSelector('.item-info li');
    const format = await page.$eval('.item-info li', li => li.innerText);

    //Publisher
    await page.waitForSelector('div.biblio-wrap > div > ul > li:nth-child(4) > span > a > span'); 
    const publisher = await page.$eval('div.biblio-wrap > div > ul > li:nth-child(4) > span > a > span', span => span.innerText);

    //Year
    await page.waitForSelector('div.biblio-wrap > div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > span'); 
    const year = await page.$eval('div.biblio-wrap > div > ul > li:nth-child(3) > span', span => span.innerText);
    const newyear = year.slice(-4)

    // Price
    try {
        await page.waitForSelector('div.price.item-price-wrap.hidden-xs.hidden-sm > span', { timeout: 1000 });
        const price = await page.$eval('div.price.item-price-wrap.hidden-xs.hidden-sm > span', span => span.innerText);
        var newprice = price.slice(-6);
    } catch {
        await page.waitForSelector('p.list-price'); 
        const price = await page.$eval('p.list-price', p => p.innerText);
        var newprice = price.slice(-6);
    } finally {
        await page.waitForSelector('div.price.item-price-wrap.hidden-xs.hidden-sm > span.sale-price'); 
        const price = await page.$eval('div.price.item-price-wrap.hidden-xs.hidden-sm > span.sale-price', span => span.innerText);
        var newprice = price.slice(-6);
    }

    
    // console.log(title);
    // console.log(author);
    // console.log(genre);
    // console.log(format);
    // console.log(publisher);
    // console.log(newyear);
    // console.log(newprice);

    return {
        title: title,
        author: author,
        genre: genre,
        format: format,
        publisher: publisher,
        year: newyear,
        price: newprice
    }

};


function readCsvAsync(filename, delimiter=',', encoding='utf-8') {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const rows = [];
        try {
            fs.createReadStream(filename, {encoding: encoding})
                .pipe(parse({delimiter: delimiter}))
                .on('data', (row) => rows.push(+row.CODECONTENT))
                .on('end', () => resolve(rows))
                .on('error', reject);
        } catch (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    });
}

async function upcData() {
    try {
        const rows = await readCsvAsync('Book_Bulk.csv', ':');
        // console.log(csvData);
        // call puppeteer or whatever
        return rows;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}


async function main(){

    const allupcs = await upcData();
  
    // console.log(allupcs);
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false, defaultViewport: null, args: ['--start-maximized']});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    const scrapedData = [];

    for(let upc of allupcs){
        const data = await getpageData(page,upc);
        scrapedData.push(data);
    }

    console.log(scrapedData);
  
  }

main();
```

Answer (score 0):

To read your CSV file, I would recommend this:

```js
fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    const AllContacts = data.split('\n')
    AllContacts.forEach((el) => {
        // And to access specific data
        const date = el[0]
        const quanity = el[1]
        const name = el[2]
        const codeContent = el[3]
        const codeType = el[4]
    })
})
```